# SQL Server: auto-generate records in a range with filtering?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We're building a simple scheduling platform using SQL Server as the backend database (with ASP.NET as the web API).

The relevant tables in the database are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmpID INT NOT NULL,      -- identity column
    FirstName VARCHAR(64),   
    LastName VARCHAR(64),
    ...                      -- other columns identifying the employee
    IsActive BIT NOT NULL    -- false if employee shouldn't show as available
)

CREATE TABLE Shifts
(
    ShiftID INT NOT NULL,    -- identity column
    EmpID INT NOT NULL,      -- foreign key
    startTime TIME NOT NULL, -- only the time of day
    endTime TIME NOT NULL, 
    expiryDate DATE,         -- no availability after this day
    weekdayMask INT NOT NULL -- 0x01 = Monday, 0x04 = Wednesday, etc. ORed together
)

CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
    ApptID INT NOT NULL,     -- identity column
    EmpID INT NOT NULL,      -- foreign key
    apptDate DATE            -- day appointment takes place
    startTime TIME NOT NULL, -- only the time of day
    endTime TIME NOT NULL,
)
```

I'm now trying to write a table function (or a stored procedure could do it too) that will obtain a calendar of availability for a given employee, given the employee's ID and a date. I need to take a few things into account:

- Assume all appointments occur in discrete half-hour blocks. An appointment is allowed to be multiple consecutive blocks. We round up to the next block, so if an appointment says it ends at 1:33 PM, the 1:30-2:00PM block should still be considered occupied.
- An employee must be present for an entire block to be available. If the employee says their shift ends at 4:45 PM, then 4:30 should not be a valid block starting time.
- An employee can have multiple shifts per day, e.g. 9 AM - 12 PM, and 1 PM to 5 PM.
- (The easy part) The function should show nothing for an employee who is unavailable, and should show nothing if the employee's `expiryDate` has passed.
- The desired return from the function is a list of **half hour blocks** that the employee is available during, listed by start block time.

Example: Assume employee 1 has a shift from 9 AM to 3 PM. Employee 1 has an appointment scheduled from 10 AM to 11 AM already, and one from 1:30 PM to 2 PM. The desired return from the function would be a list like this:

```
AvailableBlockStartingTime
--------------------------
9:00 AM
9:30 AM
11:00 AM 
11:30 AM
12:00 PM
12:30 PM
1:00 PM
2:00 PM
2:30 PM
```

So basically, I need to conditionally generate records at a given interval - in this case a half hour - but skip records if an appointment record exists for the given time block.

The "naive" thing I've been able to do is to test a given time and see if an employee is available for an appointment at that time, e.g. given "today" and "11:30 AM", I can determine whether the employee is available or not.

So I need to either automatically repeat the above in half-hour steps, and add all the results to a "table" that I can return, or use some kind of SQL magic that will generate "ranges" of records, and then exclude things from those ranges.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of generating a set of time ranges can be solved with an adhoc query, a time table.

```
declare @starttime time(0) = '09:00';
declare @endtime   time(0) = '15:00';
with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
/* adhoc time range table */
, blocks as (
  select top (48) 
      [block]=convert(time(0),dateadd(minute,30*(row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1),0))
    , [next_block]=convert(time(0),dateadd(minute,30*(row_number() over (order by (select 1))),0))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto
  order by row_number() over (order by (select 1))
)
select *
from blocks b
where b.block >= @starttime
  and b.block  < @endtime;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WJZY39264

returns:

```
+----------+------------+
|  block   | next_block |
+----------+------------+
| 09:00:00 | 09:30:00   |
| 09:30:00 | 10:00:00   |
| 10:00:00 | 10:30:00   |
| 10:30:00 | 11:00:00   |
| 11:00:00 | 11:30:00   |
| 11:30:00 | 12:00:00   |
| 12:00:00 | 12:30:00   |
| 12:30:00 | 13:00:00   |
| 13:00:00 | 13:30:00   |
| 13:30:00 | 14:00:00   |
| 14:00:00 | 14:30:00   |
| 14:30:00 | 15:00:00   |
+----------+------------+
```

---

Decoding your `weekdayMask` can get brittle if you are depending on Monday to be the first day of the week and using `datepart(weekday,...)` (this changes based on language settings, and is overridden with `set datefirst`).

My solution would be to check the `datename()` of the `weekday` and pull the associated value from a table, (here I use a table value constructor in a common table expression instead.)

The other critiera can be applied using joins, `where`, `isnull()` or `coalesce()` to deal with `null` values (for `expiryDate`), a subquery to get the related value for a weekday to compare to the `weekdayMask`, and `not exists()` to check for overlaps.

The final question is whether or not to use a procedure or table-valued function. If you were going to use a table-valued function, I would strongly suggest using an inline table valued function for the significant performance improvement over a comparable multi-statement table valued function. Since that seemed a little more tricky to write than a procedure, that is the one I chose for this answer.

Rewriting a table valued function as a procedure should be pretty easy if you decide you that is what you would prefer.

```
create function dbo.udf_availability_by_empId_Date (
    @empid int
  , @date date
) returns table with schemabinding as return (
/* Weekday mask using weekday names
   to avoid any issue with datefirst and datepart()
   this uses a 7 row lookup table for the bitmask check */
with Mask as (
  select weekday_name, weekday_value
  from (values ('Monday',1) ,('Tuesday',2) ,('Wednesday',4) ,('Thursday',8)
 ,('Friday',16) ,('Saturday',32) ,('Sunday',64))  w (weekday_name,weekday_value))
/* adhoc numbers table to generate range in half hour increments */
, n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
/* adhoc time range table */
, blocks as (
  select top (48) 
      [block]=convert(time(0),dateadd(minute,30*(row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1),0))
    , [next_block]=convert(time(0),dateadd(minute,30*(row_number() over (order by (select 1))),0))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto
  order by row_number() over (order by (select 1))
)
select b.block
from dbo.employee e
  inner join dbo.shifts s
    on s.EmpId = e.Empid
  inner join blocks b
   on b.block >= s.starttime
   and b.block < s.endtime
where e.EmpId = @empid
  and e.IsActive = 1
  and isnull(s.ExpiryDate,'20630405') >= @date
  /* get the value to check against the weekday bitmask */
  and s.weekdaymask & (
    select weekday_value
    from Mask
    where weekday_name = datename(weekday,@date)
    ) != 0
  /* check for appointments that overlap the block */
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from dbo.appointment a
    where a.endtime > b.block
      and b.next_block > a.starttime
      and a.apptDate = @date
      and a.Empid = @empid
    )
);
go
```

If you want to change the display of the `time` returned, then you can use `convert(varchar(10),a.block,100)` to get an AM/PM formatted string, but I would recommend letting your application layer do the formating.

For your testcase:

```
select 
    a.block
  , AvailableBlockStartingTime = convert(varchar(10),a.block,100) 
from dbo.udf_availability_by_empId_Date(1,'20170416') as a
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TXBUP51531

returns:

```
+----------+----------------------------+
|  block   | AvailableBlockStartingTime |
+----------+----------------------------+
| 09:00:00 | 9:00AM                     |
| 09:30:00 | 9:30AM                     |
| 11:00:00 | 11:00AM                    |
| 11:30:00 | 11:30AM                    |
| 12:00:00 | 12:00PM                    |
| 12:30:00 | 12:30PM                    |
| 13:00:00 | 1:00PM                     |
| 14:00:00 | 2:00PM                     |
| 14:30:00 | 2:30PM                     |
+----------+----------------------------+
```

---

Since it is a table valued function we might as have some fun with `apply()`.

```
/* show all employee availability for a given date */
select 
    e.EmpId
  , e.FirstName
  , e.IsActive
  , a.block
from dbo.Employee e
  outer apply dbo.udf_availability_by_empId_Date(e.EmpId,'20170416') a
```

returns:

```
+-------+----------------------+----------+----------+
| EmpId |      FirstName       | IsActive |  block   |
+-------+----------------------+----------+----------+
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 09:00:00 |
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 09:30:00 |
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 11:00:00 |
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 11:30:00 |
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 12:00:00 |
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 12:30:00 |
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 13:00:00 |
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 14:00:00 |
|     1 | fdmillion            | True     | 14:30:00 |
|     2 | shift expired person | True     | NULL     |
|     3 | inactive person      | False    | NULL     |
|     4 | other person         | True     | NULL     |
+-------+----------------------+----------+----------+
```

---

Or checking the schedule for an employee for a week:

```
/* show a weeks worth of availability for a given empid */
declare @empid    int = 1
declare @fromdate date = '20170410';
;with n as (select [Date]=dateadd(day,n,@fromdate) from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) t(n))
select 
    [Date] = convert(char(10),n.[Date],120)
  , Weekday_Name = datename(weekday,n.[Date]) 
  , a.block
from n
  outer apply dbo.udf_availability_by_empId_Date(@empid,[Date]) a
order by n.[Date]
```

returns:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+
|    Date    | Weekday_Name |  block   |
+------------+--------------+----------+
| 2017-04-10 | Monday       | NULL     |
| 2017-04-11 | Tuesday      | NULL     |
| 2017-04-12 | Wednesday    | NULL     |
| 2017-04-13 | Thursday     | NULL     |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 09:00:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 09:30:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 10:00:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 10:30:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 11:00:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 11:30:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 12:00:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 12:30:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 13:00:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 13:30:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 14:00:00 |
| 2017-04-14 | Friday       | 14:30:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 09:00:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 09:30:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 10:00:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 10:30:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 11:00:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 11:30:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 12:00:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 12:30:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 13:00:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 13:30:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 14:00:00 |
| 2017-04-15 | Saturday     | 14:30:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 09:00:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 09:30:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 11:00:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 11:30:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 12:00:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 12:30:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 13:00:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 14:00:00 |
| 2017-04-16 | Sunday       | 14:30:00 |
+------------+--------------+----------+
```

---

Additional note: `time(0)` is 3 bytes vs. 5 bytes for `time` (the default fractional precision is 7). You can shave 4 bytes of each row by including a precision of 0-2.

Reference:

- [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)
- [table value constructor `(values (...),(...))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)
- [`apply()`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)
- [**`set datefirst`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

Comment: Extremely comprehensive. I didn't need everything you wrote, but I was able to pick from it what I needed to generate the records necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Main thing is that you didn't provide any sample data.
Also in your script above only Example part is important.

I mean is it necessary to understand those points in bullets.

IF I hv understood correctly then it is not so complicated.
Else Tell me what i hvn't understood.

```
DECLARE @Shift table(empid int,starttime time(0),endtime time(0))
insert into @Shift VALUES(1,'9:00 AM','3 PM')
--select * from @Shift
declare @Appointment table(empid int,starttime time(0),endtime time(0))

insert into @Appointment VALUES(1,'10:00 AM','11:00 AM')
,(1,'1:30 PM','2:00 PM')
--select * from @Appointment

declare @intervalInMin int=30
;with GENCTE as
(
select cast('12:00 AM' as time) as Caltime
union ALL
select dateadd(MINUTE,@intervalInMin,Caltime)
from gencte
where Caltime<=cast('23:00' as time)
)
select caltime AvailableBlockStartingTime
 from gencte g
where exists(select empid  from @Shift s
where g.caltime between s.starttime and s.endtime
and not EXISTS
(
select empid from @Appointment a where s.empid=a.empid
and g.caltime between a.starttime and a.endtime
)

)
```